# What's the %HOMEPATH%\.nuget\packages folder for?

Tags: nuget

I see that the folder `%HOMEPATH%\.nuget\packages` has many nuget package downloads.

What's this folder for? Is it so that every time I download any NuGet package on my machine using the PowerShell or the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio, the package is first cached in this location? That seems like the only plausible answer but I'd like to confirm.

When do packages get added to this folder and who adds them?

Comment: It is just the nuget cache, so it does not have to download the same packages over and over again.

Comment: Wonderful. Put that down as an answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just the nuget cache, so it does not have to download the same packages over and over again.

It is managed by Nuget itself. If you find it gets too big (and it does), there is nothing wrong with deleting it.